# Dealing with a large string in Gherkin with Scenario Outline

Tags: bdd, behat, gherkin

I'm using Behat for BDD and using [Scenario Outlines](http://docs.behat.org/guides/1.gherkin.html#scenario-outlines) so I can easily do the same test with other data. But I got a problem with large texts. See example below:

```
Scenario Outline: create a thing
  When I click on "New"
  Then I should be at "/thing/new"
  When I fill in "title" with <title>
  When I fill in "description" with "description"
  When I click on "save"
  Then I should be at "/things"
  Then I should see <title> in the list
  When I click on <title>
  Then I should see <title>
  Then I should see <description>

  Examples:
    | title          | description |
    | "My new thing" | "a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string" |
```

As you can imagine this can be annoying if there are more large texts or more type of values. Is there a solution for this? For example using a variable? Which could be something like this:

```
$myvar = "a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string"

Scenario Outline: create a thing
  When I click on "New"
  Then I should be at "/thing/new"
  When I fill in "title" with <title>
  When I fill in "description" with "description"
  When I click on "save"
  Then I should be at "/things"
  Then I should see <title> in the list
  When I click on <title>
  Then I should see <title>
  Then I should see <description>

  Examples:
    | title          | description |
    | "My new thing" | $myvar      |
```

Answer (score 2):

If it was me I'd write the Scenario at a much higher level. What is the requirement you're describing? If it's that "Things" can have descriptions of up to 500 characters (or whatever), then say that instead of having an arbitrary long string:

```
When I fill in "description" with a 500 character description
....
Then the new thing should have a description 500 characters long
 And the new thing's description should match the description entered
```

Your When step implementation could then generate 500 characters of Lorem Ipsum data, enter it into the form and store it in the Scenario context for checking later.

It isn't pretty but:

1. It describes the requirement better than an random "long string"
2. It keeps the Feature files cleaner and more concise

It might be worth applying the same "What requirement am I describing?" question to the rest of the scenario as well. There's a lot going on here that personally I'd split into multiple Scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I do think it is better to test with real world examples. So in this case the long string value would have a value the client wants to give to it. So I would like to use something like a defined variable to keep the Examples part cleaner.

Comment: That's always the trouble with these questions, making them generic enough that they'll make sense to everyone but not so generic that they don't have all the detail.

If there's some real world data then I'd put that in a separate Fixtures.php file which where they'd then be available to all your Step implementations. I don't know Behat well enough to recommend exactly how to do that though so I'll leave the detailed answer to someone else.

Comment: I agree with James' observation. Gherkin should describe the behavior of the system or descriptive action of the user. As a thumb rule, I won't add any thing that doesn't have a business value. So, clicking button to submit form doesn't have business value in most cases but submitting form itself has a business value. But, going back to your original question, in your case it might be a better option to handle this large text inside your step definition. Gherkin isn't a good tool to handle large string like you described.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can have variables as you exemplified with `$myvar`. If James McCalden's suggestion does not suit you, having the content in an external file may be close enough to your `$myvar` suggestion, e.g.:

```
Scenario Outline: create a thing
  When I ... 
  ...
  Then I should see <title>
  Then I should see <description>

  Examples:
    | title          | description |
    | "My new thing" | /mydir/myvar.txt |
```

Then  `/mydir/myvar.txt` in the *test resources* directory would contain:

```
a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string a very large string
```

And finally in your steps class:

```
 @Then("Then I should see (.+)")
 public void thenISouldSee(String param) {
       param = process(param);
       ...
 }

 private String process(String parameter) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
       return parameter.charAt(0) == '/' ? readFile(parameter) : parameter;
 }

 private String readFile(String dir) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        File file = new File(BrandsContentManagementSteps.class.getResource(dir).toURI());
        return FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 }
```

Note that FileUtils requires importing [apache commons.io](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6).